# Cygwin runtime errors ("couldn't allocate cygwin heap")

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cygwin

I am getting following exceptions when I start running some commands in Cygwin.

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe (4136): *** couldn't allocate cygwin heap, Win32 error 0,
 base 0x740000, top 0x755000, reserve_size 86016, allocsize 86016, page_const 40
96
30952849 [main] bash 7928 sync_with_child: child 4136(0x240) died before initial
ization with status code 0x1
30953019 [main] bash 7928 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash-2.05b$ ls
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe (4236): *** couldn't allocate cygwin heap, Win32 error 0,
 base 0x740000, top 0x755000, reserve_size 86016, allocsize 86016, page_const 40
96
32476910 [main] bash 7928 sync_with_child: child 4236(0x240) died before initial
ization with status code 0x1
32478264 [main] bash 7928 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If this is a memory issue, How can I increase the heap size for Cygwin, I am using windows7

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try looking at this page: http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-maxmem.html

Comment: Related (on SO): [Win 8, cygwin heap failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932874/win-8-cygwin-heap-failure) (there are a few answers with some solutions you might want to try).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic `fork()` error.  See the [relevant section in the Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures) for more information.